# Consistent 2 minute delay for multipart/form-data POSTs using Tomcat 8

Tags: java, apache, nginx, amazon-ec2, tomcat8

I'm trying to get a server up and running on EC2 using Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.0.2017.  I've been able to set up a reverse proxy using Nginx at first and then just now Apache, and everything has been working fine except that something is causing a consistent 2-minute delay when I try to POST a multipart form.  Everything goes through and works after 2 minutes, but it always takes 2 minutes for the server to do SOMETHING, what it is I don't know:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCpjV.png

I'm willing to be proven wrong, but I'm fairly certain that neither my nginx configuration nor my apache httpd configuration is at fault because I tested both of them individually and it happened under both of them, pointing to a problem with my Tomcat 8, SSL certificate, or possibly AWS configuration.  I'm also confident that there isn't a problem with my javascript code that does the POST, because it works fine on an elastic beanstalk environment tomcat build.

This only seems to occur with multi-part form data POSTs, but that's not to say I know that nothing else is affected.  I've tried monitoring TCP traffic and looking at error logs and nothing seems out of place, there's just a 2 minute delay that occurs before my java controller receives the form and I'm baffled.

Anyone have any idea what might be happening?  Any ideas, vague or not, about leads or suggestions of things to do would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps it has to do with the DNS settings on the machine making the requests.